# Why does copying a large file cause so much memory activity?

Tags: windows

I'm currently copying six large files across a 100MBit/s network from my Windows XP system to a Windows 2003 server. My PC is rather unresponsive and when I look at perfmon, I see that PhysicalDisk and Processor is bouncing around 20% but memory (pages/sec) is at solid maximum.

What is causing this? I thought the memory monitor was a generally indicating how much virtual memory page was being used.

Comment: Later... hmm, the copy failed to finish (will switch to using robocopy) - it looked like the Windows 2003 server fell off the network briefly. tcpsvcs.exe is consuming 600MB of RAM and a quick Google on this indicates this isn't unknown. Still intruiged why the client Windows XP system was thrashing memory

Answer (score 1):

How large are the files? Have a look at [Slow Large File Copy Issues](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/05/08/slow-large-file-copy-issues.aspx). 
[This thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/37605/copying-large-file-to-remote-server-causes-it-to-run-out-of-physical-memory) discusses it a bit more with some work-arounds and such.
I've switched to using [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) when copying large files.

Comment: The files were huge video files - about 30GB. Will check out richcopy. Often used robocopy but always on look out for good alternatives.